# How can I update vSync settings after creating an SDL_Renderer?

Tags: sdl2, vsync

I have an `SDL_Renderer` which I set to use or not use vSync depending on the user). In my options menu I have an option for enabling/disabling vSync. Can I edit my renderer to update the vSync preferences so that I don't have to destroy and recreate it? Doing so would invalidate a lot of renderer pointers in my game, so I would like to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I asked on the SDL Forums too:

- There is no way to edit vSync settings after renderer creation without using OpenGL.
- [Destroying the renderer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/114131/62216) and re-creating it, is not an option because it will destroy every texture created with it.

So vSync shouldn't be an user-editable setting (at least for now).

Comment: Why not just reload textures with the new renderer?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 That would be hell of a work, updating EVERY pointer, plus not worth it.

Comment: That just depends on *your* architecture, in some cases (like in my game) textures are stored in a single place, and updating them would be really easy.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 That wouldn't be updating, that would be reloading every texture: an useless operation

Comment: Not useless; you could make VSync toggleable.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got a minus one. It explains quite clearly that it can't be done unless the renderer is destroyed. Why the OP decided not to do it shouldn't change the quality of that answer. Plus one from me.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.0.18 you can use [SDL_RenderSetVSync](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetVSync):

> Toggle VSync of the given renderer.
>
> **Syntax**
> `int SDL_RenderSetVSync(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int vsync);`

`vsync` can be set 1 for on or 0 for off (other values are reserved).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with a brief explanation of your solution, and maybe a small usage example.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: The following only works when executed before calling `SDL_CreateRenderer`. Seems like SDL has made a simple and trivial task quite hard.

SDL wiki suggests that calling `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1" or "0");` should do the trick.
You might also want to try [SDL_SetHintWithPriority](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetHintWithPriority), which will override any possible environment variables that have been set that could prevent that value passed in to `SDL_SetHint` to have an effect.

Comment: [Here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC) says that this hint is used in `SDL_CreateRenderer()` if `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` isn't passed. Btw, is there any way to test if vSync is being effectively active?

Comment: You should be able to see whether VSYNC is active by disabling your framerate limiting code and then calculating your framerate. With VSYNC on, the framerate should be ~60, and without it much higher. I'll see if I can get this working on my game.

Comment: Could you drop by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) so we could discuss this better there?

Comment: Tested it right now, not working. :(