# Will SDL_DestroyRenderer() destroy every texture created with it?

Tags: sdl2

The documentation [on the SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyRenderer) states:

> Use this function to destroy the rendering context for a window and **free associated textures**

So does this mean that **every** texture I create will be freed (even those still used) or **only the ones that were destroyed manually** (by using `SDL_DestroyTexture()`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that all existing textures are freed. I checked the SDL source and inside the `SDL_DestroyRenderer` function they do this:

```
while (renderer->textures) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(renderer->textures);
}
```

So **every** texture that was created with the renderer gets destroyed.